# I need small tests to practice on

Tags: javascript

I am looking for small exercises to do with javascript. I found a few, such as http://www.ling.gu.se/~lager/kurser/webtechnology/lab4.html, which was great, and zipped right through. I also found http://code.google.com/codejam/ which was AWESOME but each one is taking about a day for me.

tl;dr : Im looking for mid level programing exercises to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always try to do the exercises from [ProjectEuler](http://www.projecteuler.net), although I must admit I am not entirely sure what type of exercises you were looking for.

Comment: simple stuff, object oriented javascript tasks would be ideal, stuff that shows design patterns, but anything interesting, really.

edit : projecteuler looks like fun! Thanks!

Comment: Was going to suggest this :o) ++

Answer (score 0):

Take on your own project! Make something cool/useful, and then learn the code necessary to complete it.

Comment: I do. Most of its hideous. Little of it is actually useful. All fun though!